# Product and Chain rule derivative

Tags: calculus, products, chain-rule

How to differentiate $\frac{2x}{(4x-3)^3}$ using the quotient rule?
How to differentiate $y= 2x(4x-3)^{-3}$ keeping it in powers form?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What have you tried with this problem? How much do you know about the various differentiation rules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotient rule is given by
$$ \frac{(d'u-u'd)}{d^2}  $$
where $d'$ is the derivative of the denominator and $u'$ is the derivative of the numerator. Apply this formula and you will have your solution. If you are having trouble with this formula, please explain what you have tried.

If you are having trouble with the chain rule, the chain rule is given by
$$ (f \circ g)'(x)=f'(g(x))g'(x). $$

For example, consider $f(x)=(2x+1)^4$ where $g(x)=2x+1$. Then,
$$ g'(x) = 2.$$
Therefore,
$$ f'(x) = 4(2x+1)^3 \times 2 = 8(2x+1)^3.$$

Comment: im unsure of what the derivative of (4x-3)^-3 is. and then how to apply that to the formula

Comment: Are you with familiar chain rule? The chain rule is what you use to compute the derivative of the denominator.

Comment: can you please explain with an example,

Comment: I modified my answer to include the chain rule as well as an example.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

For the quotient let apply

$$\left(\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}\right)'=\frac{f'(x)\cdot g(x)-g'(x)f(x)}{g^2(x)}$$

and for the power

$$(f(x)h^n(x))'=f'(x)h^n(x)+f(x)\cdot nh^{n-1}(x)$$